# How to create Outlook Web addin with third party login

Tags: outlook, oauth, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

given [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/overview-authn-authz) link there are couple of options for login/authentication, 
but i am not able to follow.
MY requirement is
after installing  Outlook Web addin  user should be able to login into third party(NimbleWork) app. 
For example [asana for outook](https://asana.com/apps/outlook) it gives login facility into their application. 
I have oauth details with me but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement any authentication mechanism in your add-in. The [Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui) provides everything for that, see [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) for more information.

But I'd suggest starting with SSO first. Users sign in to Office using either their personal Microsoft account or their Microsoft 365 Education or work account. Take advantage of this and use single sign-on (SSO) to authenticate and authorize the user to your add-in without requiring them to sign in a second time. The [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) article explains how to configure your add-in for using SSO.

Comment: thanks for the response, however i still did not understand use of sign-on (SSO) to authenticate, i read about it, MS docs says i need to sso when i want to use MS 365 services. what if i login with ajax request with office dialog api and save access token in Office.context.roamingSettings-- will this help to prevent login every time?  actully  i am new to this can you explain...

Comment: You can choose any method of authentication, that is solely up to you. But you are right, you need to SSO if you want to use MS 365 services.

Comment: thanks for response i understand now, i cannot save oauth details in client side code
is there any way to save custom oauth details into azure portal and get these details on client side for firing rest apis 
currently i am able to login with oauth details but all details are saved on js files.
i dont need to access in of MS 365 services.

Comment: See [Authenticate and authorize with the Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api) for more information.